# Open the Url in a different tab/window on the submit button click

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, submit

I have a submit button like:

```
<form id="distribut" action = @Model.RedirectUrl method="post">
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderToken)
         <input type="hidden" name="wwwww" value="1" />
         <input type ="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

The `Model.RedirectUrl` is not a url in my own site/application.
It may vary based on some condition

The question is:

Can I open the `RedirectUrl` in a different tab/window on the submit button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add `target="_blank"` to your form. But of course you will need to do some validation before trigering.

Comment: sorry being out for the weekend. what I suggested was to validate your form fields before redirecting, if not, the redirecting is triggered whenever the button is clicked, even the form is empty. hope this makes sense to you.